# changing the behavior for the unobtrusive validation in asp.net-mvc-3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I want to change the default behavior for the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`

I want to be able to change options like the error message placement or highlight a field when an error is happening , etc

all that I could do using the `jquery.validate` plugin alone. Just change some of the `validate` method options like `highlight` or `errorPlacement`

so I want to override some of the functionality of the unobtrusive validation , is it possible without changing the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` file

Comment: $.validator.setDefaults() in your comment does it!  Below it is too hard to find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could fetch the native validator from the form data and then subscribe to any [standard option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options). For example `errorPlacement`:

```
$(function() {
    var validator = $('form').data('validator');
    validator.settings.errorPlacement = function(error, element) {
        // do your custom error placement
    };

    validator.settings.highlight = function(element, errorClass) {
        // do your custom error highlight
    };
});
```

Comment: there is no way to override these options before the unobtrusive validation starts ?

Comment: What do you mean by *before unobtrusive validation starts*? Unobtrusive validation starts when the user attempts to submit the form. In the example I have shown you are directly plugging into the jquery validator settings when the DOM is ready and overriding the default settings. Isn't what you were looking for? If not, what are you looking for?

Comment: i mean the unobtrusive validation at this point already have queried the page and invoked the validate function and passed it its options, can i change these options before then ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking and what the problem is with my example and why it doesn't meet your requirements. In the example I have shown you are changing those options. If you don't like the way unobtrusive validation works you could get rid of it and hook the jquery validate plugin directly. Personally that's what I do.

Comment: yes its exactly what i am looking for but the comment is just for performance , is there is a way to change the functionality without making extra queries to the page ? a normal way of thinking if there were events triggered in the code and i listen to them or by using call back functions to change the behavior

Comment: a very side question , what do you use instead of it ?

Comment: If you are afraid of performance impact, although you absolutely shouldn't with this code, simply give your form an id and replace `$('form')` with `$('#your_form_id')`. But honestly don't do premature optimizations. And for your side question: I use the `jquery.validate` plugin.

Comment: i have found we could use `$.validator.setDefaults()` that will override the settings without querying the page

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I have updated the highlight function after retrieving the     $('#myform').data('validator') in     $(document).ready().  For some reason, it just keeps resetting to the original highlight function every second validation. I am not able to understand why this is happening - any suggestions?